# Input and TextArea change background when validation doesn't pass

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got required input fields on my form. If the user submits the form and doesn't fill out the input field they receive a validation error.

**Goal**
I want the fields background to change to red when ModelState is not Valid. How can I achieve that?

**I've tried adding this in my CSS file** - but when I submit the form I noticed that the class input-validation-error is not added to my input or textarea I have in my form.

```
.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

**Models**

```
public class userInfo
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "first Name")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }
}
```

**Views**

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })      
}

<input class="lbl-info" id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" value="@ViewBag.first_name"/>
```

**Controllers**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(User user)
{
    ...

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.first_name = user.first_name;
    }   

    return ...
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the Razor Html helper to render your input? `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.first_name)` Also, are you using the jquery unobtrusive validation library?

Comment: It's my first time trying out MVC. (Still learning...) I started without razor because it made more sense to me at that time... I'm not using unobtrusive jquery validation library @zgood

Comment: Ok I see. Well if you have `@model userInfo` at the top of your View you can pass your model back to your view (`return View(user);`) after it fails validation. It will contain all the field values so you don't have to set them in the ViewBag. Also rendering out the input using the Razor Html helper will add all the attributes to your input needed for client side validation from the attributes you define in your ViewModel (`[Required]`, etc)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. I applied that and got the border I was looking for and didn't have to put the viewbag in the value area. @zgood